# Set logo custom width / height in stencil Theme (Cornerstone-Light)

Tags: bigcommerce

is there a way to specify custom logo width / height in cornerstone theme? When uploading the logo having size 1200 * 1000 it will make the logo 250*100 every time. if we did it by css it will break logo in large screen.

Can anyone let us know how to remove this 250*100 and use custom width / height?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Stencil Editor.  Go to 'Storefront Design', 'My Themes', then 'Customize'.  Once you are in the editor go to 'Logo' and change logo size to 'Specify dimension'.  There you can put in the image dimensions you need.  Don't forget to save changes and apply to your store.